# Trying to sort two columns without selecting the sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to sort a range from a sheet that won't always be the active one. But it always sorts the equivalent range of the active sheet.

```
function sortColumns() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var range = sheet.getRange('B2:C3');
  range.sort({column: 2, ascending: true});
}
```

I thought this code would always sort the selected range from the sheet A1, but it's sorting the selected range of the active sheet instead.

Comment: The fact that it's selected means its active, if the range is selected, it is active,which makes the sheet active (you can get that range using the [selection class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/selection)). if you want to work with inactive ranges you'll have to get them with the regular `getRange()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
function sortColumns() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('A1');
  var range = sh.getRange(ss.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getA1Notation());
  range.sort({column: 2, ascending: true});
}
```

but I'm not sure.

> After rereading I realize that you wanted the selected range.  The selected range only applies to the active sheet.

Comment: It shows the same error as the other script. For some reason it's trying to sort the active sheet instead of the sheet A1 (I just edited the original question, to name it Sheet1 instead of A1).

Comment: So I can't sort a selected range of a sheet that isn't active?